# How to get the React router path on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this `App.jsx` that routes to (renders) different components.

But I have set `<NavigationBar />` and an `h1` tag between `Router` and `Switch` because I need to render those two components for every page.

So now what I want is to get the current route name/path name that displays on the browser address bar. This path is changing when I click on different links (`Link`) to render different components.

But the path value is the same `/` even though the path is changing for every `Link` click.
I even used `componentDidUpdate` but it didn't work as it gave the error

> maximum update depth exceeded componentdidupdate

this is my `App.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "./css/custom.css";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import NavigationBar from "./pages/homepage-components/1-navbar";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import Post from "./pages/Post";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentPath: "",
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      currentPath: window.location.pathname,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        {/* --------------- Navigation Bar --------------- */}
        <NavigationBar />
        <h1>Path is: {this.state.currentPath}</h1>
        {/* --------------- End of Navigation Bar --------------- */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/post" component={Post} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Even though the different components are rendered as path changes, the value for `this.state.currentPath` doesn't update.

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook provides current location:

```
function NavigationHeader() {
    const location = useLocation();
    return <h1>Path is: {location.pathname}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Hi, and how can I set this return value to the `state` in react? just by simply calling `NavigationHeader.toString` ?